# DM Script, why does the fourier transform of gaussian-kenel needs modulus

Tags: fft, dm-script, gaussianblur

Recently I learn DM_Script for TEM image processing
I needed Gaussian blur process and I found one whose name is 'Gaussian Blur' in http://www.dmscripting.com/recent_updates.html

This code implements Gaussian blur algorithm by multiplying the fast fourier transform(FFT) of source image by the FFT of Gaussian-kernel image and finally doing inverse fourier transform of it.

Here is the part of the code,

```
// Carry out the convolution in Fourier space

compleximage fftkernelimg:=realFFT(kernelimg) (-> FFT of Gaussian-kernel image)
compleximage FFTSource:=realfft(warpimg) (-> FFT of source image)
compleximage FFTProduct:=FFTSource*fftkernelimg.modulus().sqrt()
realimage invFFT:=realIFFT(FFTProduct)
```

The point I want to ask is this
    compleximage FFTProduct:=FFTSource*fftkernelimg.modulus().sqrt()

Why does the FFT of Gaussian-kernel need '.modulus().sqrt()' for the convolution?

It is related to the fact that the fourier transform of a Gaussian function becomes another Gaussian function?
Or It is related to a sort of limitation of discrete fourier transform?

Please answer me
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the general precision limitation of any floating point numeric computing. (see f.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples), or more in depth [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html))

A rotational (real-valued) Gaussian of stand.dev. sigma should be transformed into a 100% real-values rotational Gaussioan of 1/sigma. However, doing this numerically will show you deviations: Just try the following:

```
number sigma = 30
number A0 = 1
realimage first := RealImage( "First", 8, 256, 256 )
first = A0 * exp( - (iradius**2/(2*sigma*sigma) ))
first.showimage()
complexImage second := FFT(first)
second.Showimage()

image nonZeroImaginaryMask = ( 0 != second.Imaginary() )
nonZeroImaginaryMask.Showimage()
nonZeroImaginaryMask.SetLimits(0,1)
```

When you then multiply these complex images (before back-transferring) you are introducing even more errors. By using modulus, one ensures that the forward transformed kernel is purely real and hence a better "damping" curve.

A better implementation of a FFT filtering code would actually create the FFT(Gaussian) directly with a std.dev of 1/sigma, as this is the analytically correct result. Doing a FFT of the kernel only makes sense if the kernel (or its FFT) is not analytically known.

In general: When implementing any "maths" into a program code, it can pay hugely to think it through with numerical computation limits in the back of your head. Reduce actual computation whenever possible (i.e. compute analytically and use the result instead of relying on brute force numerical computation) and try to "reshape" equations when possible, f.e. avoid large sums over many small numbers, be careful about checks against exact numeric values, try to avoid expressions which are very sensitive on small numerica errors  etc.